# How to identify a user with a not changeable number on IBM Notes

Tags: authentication, lotus-notes, lotusscript

We have a few IBM Notes databases here, at least one hundred I think, and if we have to identify a user we are using the given Name at the moment. We are also connecting this with a database of all the employees here, using it to do time-management and administrative stuff.

Therefore we need to determine which user is which, as I said we are doing that by the name at the moment. But names change, so now we would like to change to a not changing ID. I thought we could use the key identifier, or one of them at least. So my question is, is there a way to get it through Lotus Script? If not, is there another way to identify the user of a certain key-file?

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes and Domino do not have any builtin unique key identifier for users. It was never part of the design. You can't use the noteid of the Person document because that varies from one replica of the Domino Directory to another, and you should not use the unid, because although that's stable across replicas it can still change if you have to recreate the Person document, which you might have to do if the employee leaves your company and then comes back, or if the Person document is damaged.

The way most large organizations deal with this is to set the EmployeeID field in the Person document and use that as the unique identifier. Some organizations might also create unique identifiers and use them for the ShortName.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I don't diasagree with Richards answer in general, it is possible to 'capture' a Document-ID (UNID) in a separate 'created when composed' field. This will then hold a static 'unique' 32 character reference. Once this has been set, it should not change unless you have a process to change it. A UNID is based on/derived from a time-stamp so they are extremely unlikely to be reused or clash with future system generated unids, even after many years or many millions of docs being used. This captured value may or may not agree with the actual system assigned unid, but this generally doesn't matter.

If you are unhappy with a copy of an system unid, then this could be used on a temporary basis until it can be overridden with an external ID reference. Alternatively, use a proven external 'guid' reference and assign that to the records you want to track.

If the raw unid creates side issues for you, use @password to hash it to another unique value. This generates a quick/old MD5 style hash, but good enough for reference-IDs.

One other point to mention is that keeping previous names in a list is also feasible, so that matching an 'old name' is still viable. Either create an additional field in the person doc (admins may hate you for doing this) or add older names to the 'fullname' field list. This usually contains a list of name variations. If you add the older name to the bottom of the list (ie: append) the you and the system can match against this name (for logins and routing) but Notes only ever uses the first name in the list as the users 'official' name (for reader/author fields etc), which should be the current name. To find the name, just lookup the name in the ($Users) view if using the FullName field or create a new view in using your own field (again Admins may hate you more).